# How to get transaction information from PayPal donation?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I have a Donate button which was created using Paypal website, but what do I have to do if I want to save some information like if the transaction status, the value of the donation, etc..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Info:**

1. Usually in most cases you can gather that information from running a
   history report or you can drill down and create a transaction detail report from the reports option (more / reports | may vary on UI); view the donation contents such as transaction ID, donation amount, ect.
2. You can also create an [IPN script](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/?mark=ipn) to gather this data

**Simple Solution:**

3. You can view the contents of each donation as well through the PayPal email notification

Hope this helps!